# How to do this specifically things in CSS for a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I want to do some things with my table but I think an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QqK7.jpg) would sum it up as my english is not the best.

I want to first move the second button to the left. Just one button on each corner on top of my table.
And secondly I want to avoid my input textbox (or a button later) to resieze the whole row of the 2nd header.

Any help will do. I can't figure it out by myself.

**Code**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reset filters", "Index",
            null,
            new { @class = "btn btn-success custom", @style = "color:white", @role = "button" }
            )

<button class="btn btn-default custom" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> Export to Excel</button>

<div style="padding-top: 12px"></div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Materials", FormMethod.Get))
    {           
        <div id="grid-list">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_AjaxMaterialList", Model); }
        </div>
    }
```

**Partial View Code**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc <!--import this so we get our HTML Helper-->

@model IPagedList<eContentMVC.Models.Material>

<!-- import the included stylesheet for some (very basic) default styling -->
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@*<div style="padding-top: 14px"></div>*@

<div class="panel panel-primary filterable" style="padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">GDS eContent Master Data Service Tool</h3>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:14%">Brand</th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:25%">Category</th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:13%">Language</th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:7%">BCO</th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:9%">Material Cod</th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:7%">Derivation</th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:7%">Artwork</th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:7%">Delivery</th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="width:5%">Export</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="height:4%"><input type="text" /></th>
                <th class="centerAlign"><input type="text" /></th>
                <th class="centerAlign"><input type="text" /></th>
                <th class="centerAlign"><input type="text" /></th>
                <th class="centerAlign"><input type="text" /></th>
                <th class="centerAlign"><input type="text" /></th>
                <th class="centerAlign"><input type="text" /></th>
                <th class="centerAlign"><input type="text" /></th>
                <th class="centerAlign"><input type="text" /></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            // Content 
        </tbody>

    </table>    
</div>

<div class="centerAlign" style="padding: 0px; margin: -8px">
<!-- output a paging control that lets the user navigation to the previous page, next page, etc -->
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", "Materials", new
    {
        brand_name = Request["brand_name"],
        page
    }))
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for making the table looking the right way. For the button, use bootstrap's **pull-right**.

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.mytable tr th{
    height:42px;
}
.mytable input{
    width:100%;
}
.mytable th:nth-of-type(1){
    width:14%;
}
.mytable th:nth-of-type(2){
    width:25%;
}
.mytable th:nth-of-type(3){
    width:13%;
}
.mytable th:nth-of-type(4),.mytable th:nth-of-type(6),.mytable th:nth-of-type(7),.mytable th:nth-of-type(8){
    width:7%;
}
.mytable th:nth-of-type(5){
    width:9%;
}
.mytable th:nth-of-type(9){
    width:5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary filterable">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">GDS eContent Master Data Service Tool</h3>

    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover mytable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="centerAlign">Brand</th>
                <th class="centerAlign">Category</th>
                <th class="centerAlign">Language</th>
                <th class="centerAlign">BCO</th>
                <th class="centerAlign">Material Cod</th>
                <th class="centerAlign">Derivation</th>
                <th class="centerAlign">Artwork</th>
                <th class="centerAlign">Delivery</th>
                <th class="centerAlign">Export</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
                <th class="centerAlign">
                    <input type="text" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="centerAlign" style="padding: 0px; margin: -8px"></div>
```

If it helps, +1.

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't recognize mytable class. Nothing of it works when called. 
I'm trying to figure it out what did I do wrong.

Comment: Did you put the css where it should be?

Comment: Manually adding `style="box-sizing:border-box; height:42px"` to the `th` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Use a css file. Like this <link href="path/to/cssfile/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: It won't recognize them for some reason. Yet I manually added the `height` and it did fine. `box-sizing` didn't do anything but it's ok, the height is what bothered me. Answer accepted.

Comment: I added box-sizing because it was a prerequesite of bootstrap and I didn't use the bootstrap's css. I am sorry I didn't tell you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Without the real page i'm not sure, but:

- To move the button on the right use bootstrap class `pull-right`.
- To have every row at the same height. I think td have some padding inside. Put padding to 0 and fix the height in css

  .table td {
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

Or something like this